# Where does logstash /elasticsearch write data?

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash

In my input section of my logstash config file, I have created a configuration for reading a rabbitMQ queue. Using the RabbitMQ console, I can see logstash drain the queue. However, I have no idea what logstash is doing with the message. Is it discarding it? Is if forwarding it to elasticsearch?

Here's the logstash configuration

```
 input {
  rabbitmq {
    host => "192.168.34.151"
    exchange => an_exchange
    key => a_key
    queue => a_queue
    }
 }
 output {
   elasticsearch {
     embedded => true
     protocol => http
   }
 }
```

edit - removed the bogus comma from the config.

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete logstash config file? Usually, it should contain `input{...} filter {...} output {...}`. You seem to be only showing the content of the logstash `input`, what do you have configured in your `output{...}`?

Comment: That's correct.  This is only the portion I added for reading the queue.

Comment: If your _output_ section contains a rabbitmq plugin it's publishing messages, not consuming them. Since you're specifying a queue I assume you use the rabbitmq _input_ plugin. Where the messages eventually end up depends on your output configuration.

Comment: Well that makes more sense, but when I had the config above in the input section, nothing happened. When I moved it to the output section, the queue drained.  But that's a hint that I need to move this back to the input and then create matching output goodness.

Comment: @MagnusBäck I updated the question per your suggestion. As far as I can tell, elastic search should be doing *something*.  Kibana shows no activity. RabbitMQ shows the queue being drained.

Comment: See that comma after `embedded => true`, above...

Comment: I think you may be over-thinking the output section.  Will you please give an updated view of your LS config file, please?  I would like to see how you have your input and output sections configured.

ES output doesn't require a lot of tweaking, but I would consider altering your ES config to remove the default cluster and node information and replacing it with something more meaningful (and not the default).  You can then add more to the ES output section, namely cluster and index information specific to your data.

Comment: Actually, that's about it.  It's working now. My issue boiled down to an extra comma in the config file.